# Valid certification error when build android app using React-Native in linux

Tags: react-native

I was trying to create a Hello World project with React-Native using Mint Linux.

I install all necessary tools. I use React-Native 0.54.

I was behind a proxy, I setup Android Studio and create an simple app using Android Studio and I was able to successfully create an apk.

Now I was trying to create a simple React-Native app for android.

But when I run the command "react-native run-android", I got an error

```
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use React Native anymore, but I found an answer to my problem on that.
My company blocks some sites that Gradle used to download files, the site "https://bintray.com" was one of them.
Because of that I was not able to run my React Native project.

I need to ask permission to be able to access some sites, the company firewall blocks some urls.

I don't remember exactly which sites I need to access, but if my memory is good, I remember that I see some sites on the console.
(I don't remember if I use Android Studio console or Linux Terminal)